# BinaryReader read 4 bytes and don't get expected result

Tags: c#, binary, byte

I use BinaryReader to read a file and i've problem i can't solve. (c#)

I need to read 4 bytes. When i look at these bytes with my hex viewer it's `00 00 00 13`.
So i tried `Int32 fLength = dbr.ReadInt32();` The result is 318767104 instead of 19 (what i expected and need). When i use `byte[] fLength = dbr.ReadBytes(4);` i can see that i've read the correct bytes [0] [0] [0] [19].

(i've the same problem with the folowing bytes)

How can i read these 4 bytes and get 19 as result.

Thanks in advance !

Robertico

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [little endian vs big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) problem: 318767104 = 0x13000000

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readint32.aspx):

> BinaryReader stores this data type in little endian format.

Jon Skeet's [miscutil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) has a reader that allows you to choose big or little endian.

Answer (score 1):

**for reading a binary file 4bytes together**

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int)(flstrm.Length)];
int a= System.BitConverter.ToInt32(byteArray, 0); //here 0 is the start index
lbl1.Text= a.toString();
```